# Set a default value based on another column?

Tags: sql-server, image, database-design, default-value, sqldatatypes

I have the table Employee with the columns

```
    IdEmp     int not null primary key,
    PhotoEmp  image default 'D:\Avatars\maleSilhouette.png',
    GenderEmp nchar(1) CHECK GenderEmp in ('M','F')
```

So, this script stores the male image (regardless the gender) by default everytime I insert into EMPLOYEE (IdEmp,GenderEmp) values ('1001','M'), but **I would like to store a female silhouette** (D:\Avatars\femaleSilhouette.png) **in case the gender is 'F'**.

Comment: Why do you put a default placeholder in a database in a first place? isnt it beter to store null for users who did not upload own photo?

Comment: What if there is a photo for the employee?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `PhotoEmp` column a computed column and set the value as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD PhotoEmp AS CAST
(
  CASE
  WHEN GenderEmp = 'M' THEN 'D:\Avatars\maleSilhouette.png' 
  ELSE 'D:\Avatars\femaleSilhouette.png'
  END AS image
)
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. I just test it with other data types and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual column to achieve this. But you will not able to insert any other value into that column afterwards. You will get ORA-54013.